# How can I check if there's an object with a same key and update with a same key and different properties in array(javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, socket.io

Hi I'm working on a react project using Socket.io
On client side, it updates when an user click a different button with an Object such as

```
var actionArray, setActionArray
[actionArray, setActionArray] = React.useState({})


setActionArray({key: "rgb(211,40,21)", gesture: ""})
```

As the user click a different button, only the gesture property changes.

On server side, several users will update their gesture simultaneously, and the color is used as key value to recognize different users. I want to accumulate the objects with different key in this 'colorArray' array, and update only the 'gesture' property when the user update their 'gesture' value with the same key property.

```
var colorArray = [];

socket.on("action", data => {
    notifySubscribers(data);
    console.log(data);

    if (data.actionArray) {
      colorArray.push({
        key: data.actionArray.key,
        id: id,
        gesture: data.actionArray.gesture
      });
      subscribers.forEach(socket =>
        socket.emit("colorArray", { colorArray: colorArray })
      );

      console.log(colorArray);
    }
```

With the code above, it keeps adding new objects with same key value, but how can I update the object with same key with different 'gesture' property?

Here's some of the methods I tried, and didn't work.

```
//1
    colorArray = colorArray.filter(item => item.key !== data.actionArray.key);

//2
 let updatedItem = colorArray.find(element => {
      return element.key === colorArray.key;
  });
updatedItem.gesture = data.actionArray.gesture;
```

Comment: Say you have array : var array = [{key:1,value:"test"},{key:2,value:"test2"}];
var found  = array.find(obj  => obj.key ===1); found.value = "update" . This should update the object

Answer (score 0):

You were getting close, try this.

```
if (data.actionArray) {
  let matchIndex = colorArray.findIndex(element => {
    return element.key === data.actionArray.key
  });
  updatedItem = {
    ...data.actionArray,
    id: id,
  };
  if (matchIndex > -1) {
    colorArray[matchIndex] = updatedItem;
  }  else {
    colorArray.push(updatedItem);
  }
  subscribers.forEach(socket =>
    socket.emit("colorArray", { colorArray: colorArray })
  );
  console.log(colorArray);
}
```